# c++ iterating through vector returns objects that aren't even in it

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm putting together a pinball table, and here I have a PinballTable class. I want to hold all of the game objects (pinball, bumpers, flippers, etc) in a vector, which I call _gameObjs.

When I iterate through the vector, its returning the last GameObj declared in the constructor, whether that GameObj is in the vector or not. If I add multiple GameObjs to the vector, it will return that last declared GameObj that many times. I'm transitioning from C# and collections seem to be getting the best of me, I'm totally stumped here though

Here, I'm added three objects: two bumpers and one pinball. In the update function, I'm trying to get it to output output the x size of each object just so I know it's iterating correctly. Here, for example, I haven't even added the pinball to the vector, but it's outputting the pinball's x size twice per update call.

```
#include "PinballTable.h"

GameObj* _pinball;
int TABLE_WIDTH;
int TABLE_HEIGHT;

float _tableTiltedAngle     = 6.5f;
float _radiansPerDegree     = PI / 180;
float _gravityForce         = cos( _tableTiltedAngle * _radiansPerDegree ) * GRAVITY;

vector<GameObj> _gameObjs;


PinballTable::PinballTable( const int width, const int height )
{
    TABLE_WIDTH     = width;
    TABLE_HEIGHT    = height;


    GameObj bumper1(
        GameObj::shapeCircle,
        GameObj::typeStatic,
        color4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        point2f( 300.0f, 600.0f ),
        vec2f( 40.0f, 0.0f )
        );
    _gameObjs.push_back( bumper1 );


    GameObj bumper2(
        GameObj::shapeCircle,
        GameObj::typeStatic,
        color4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        point2f( 50.0f, 200.0f ),
        vec2f( 50.0f, 0.0f )
        );
    _gameObjs.push_back( bumper2 );


    GameObj pinball( 
        GameObj::shapeCircle,
        GameObj::typeDynamic, 
        color4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 
        point2f( 100.0f, 100.0f), 
        vec2f( 20.0f, 20.0f) 
        );


    _pinball = &pinball;
}


PinballTable::~PinballTable(void)
{
}





// ------------------------------ Update Functions ------------------------------
void PinballTable::update( GameTime& gameTimer )
{
    for( vector<GameObj>::iterator i = _gameObjs.begin(); i != _gameObjs.end(); ++i )
    {
        cout << i->getSize()->x << endl;
    }
}
```

thanks for the help

get size function just returns a vector2 (x, y components) from a GameObj. The output size matches up with the last declared GameObj size in the PinballTable constructor every time

```
vec2f* GameObj::getSize( void )
{
    return &_size;
}
```

Solved:

One of the problems, as pointed out by a few, was that the GameObjs are created inside the constructor.

In the GameObj class I was not declaring the different members in the header file. Switching these members to the header file seemed to fix this, for what reason I do not know.

Comment: Not related to the issue you say you're having, but `pinball` goes out of scope at the end of your constructor so you're saving the address of a destroyed object.  A short complete example would help track down the other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created 3 GameObj inside the constructor which are going to be destructed after the constructor returns and when you add them to the vector, they are garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Is your GameObj an interface or abstract class? If so, you should not put it directly into a vector, but a pointer to it. Think of a vector as a byte-array containing of serialized copies of what you put into it (since you are coming from C# this should help). C++ does not have a uniform object representation, so it is crucial to keep in mind what space your objects require.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want,

```
for( vector<GameObj>::iterator i = _gameObjs.begin(); i != _gameObjs.end(); ++i )
{
    cout << (*i).getSize()->x << endl;
}
```

You need to get the object stored in the vector by the dereference(*) operator.

Comment: cout << *i.getSize()->x << endl;

gives me the same problem

Comment: How to know this is the size of pinball. Could you provide the source code of GetSize() function?

Comment: I still don't know what causes the issue. Could you provide the complete program, please?

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I'd use a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto const &g : _gameObjs)
    cout << g.getSize()->x << "\n";
```

This was added in C++11, so you may have to give your compiler a switch to tell it to recognize/allow C++11 constructs (e.g., you normally have to with g++).

Answer (score 0):

The way that you describe your problem, it sounds as if `_size` is a global variable, and not a member of `GameObj`